# Display custom field value instead of name in many2one Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8

I have custom field named as 'code' in **res.partner**:

```py
class cust_partner
   _inherit = 'res.partner'
   _columns = { 'code': fields.char('Code', index=True), }
```

Customized **name_get , name_search** methods to get code instead of Customer name.

It works only in Search and display name in field

In my custom class:

```py
class test_order(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'test_order'
    _columns = {'customer_code': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Code', ondelete='restrict', required=False), }
```

My expected output is in test_order class I need to display value of  'code' instead of name in field customer_code (after save in form view ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this test_order class instead.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp import models, fields, api, _
class test_order(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'test_order'

   @api.multi
   @api.depends("partner_id")
   def _compute_customer_code(self):
       for o in self:
           o.customer_code = o.partner_id.code

   customer_code = fields.Char('Code',compute=_compute_customer_code)
   partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner','Customer')
```

If you now fill in the partner_id-field. The customer_code-field will get automatically the code value from customer.

Comment: This will work but i dont want 2 fields im expecting the output of partner_id = code (default name )

Comment: The default name for a model can be set by

Comment: `_rec_name = 'code'` in your `class cust_partner` class. But you will get the code instead of name everywhere then. The same like _inherit.

Answer (score 0):

You can change displyaed value from javascript code:

```
openerp.custom_module = function(instance){

var _t = instance.web._t,
    _lt = instance.web._lt;
var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

openerp.custom_module.CustomFieldMany2One = openerp.web.form.FieldMany2One.extend(
    {
    set_value: function(value_) {
        this._super(value_);
        var self = this;
        var context = this.build_context().eval();
        var model_obj = new instance.web.Model(this.field.relation);
        model_obj.call('read', [value_[0], ['code'], context]).then(function (res) {
            if ('code' in res)
            {
                self.display_string(res['code']);
            }
        });
    },
});
openerp.web.form.widgets.add('custommany2one', 'openerp.custom_module.CustomFieldMany2One');
}
```

Use `widget` attribute in xml:

```
<field name='customer_code'  widget="custommany2one"/>
```

Comment: I did  this by customized  of read() ,name_get(),name_search() methods. Thanks